# ERROR 1318 (42000): Incorrect number of arguments for FUNCTION; expected 2, got 1

Tags: mysql

I had to create a function that shows the smallest numbers from "Datoru tehnika" category, and this is my code:

```
delimiter //
create function min_cena (Nosaukums char(30), Kategorija char(30))
Returns int(11)
begin
declare min_summa int;
set min_summa = (select min(cena) from Preces where Piegadatajs = "3" AND Kategorija = "Datoru tehnika");
return min_summa;
end //
```

And when I try to call it out, I use:

```
set @w = (select Nosaukums from Piegadataji where ID = "3");
set @r = "Datoru tehnika";
select concat(@w, " minimala cena",@r, " kategorija: ", min_cena(@r)) as "Rezultats";
end //
```

But whenever I do that, this is the error I get:

```
ERROR 1318 (42000): Incorrect number of arguments for FUNCTION eksamens.min_cena; expected 2, got 1
```

I have no idea what I should do, I tried everything I know, and nothing works.

It's probably a easy solution, yet I can't do it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are passing only one parameter to the `min_cena()` function in the second code segment.

Comment: Please check your code, you are just passing 1 @r argument, but this function needed 2 arguments.

Comment: Am I really passing only one? I use both @w and @r there... Or is somehow only one of them an argument?

Comment: @ManojSharma added a comment above, forgot to mention you, apologies.

Comment: Please try to pass like -- min_cena(@w, @r) . Please check the variables order what you want to pass.

Comment: @ManojSharma I tried --min_cena(@w, @r), and it brings out "No query specified".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
set @w = (select Nosaukums from Piegadataji where ID = "3");
set @r = "Datoru tehnika";
select concat(@w, " minimala cena",@r, " kategorija: ", min_cena(@w,@r)) as "Rezultats";
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally understood my problem now.

Comment: Could you please tell me why in the create function part, it ignores the "AND Kategorija = "Datoru tehnikas"?  There is a column called Kategorija with Datoru tehnikas in it.

Comment: the problem was you missed one parameter in `min_cena(@r)` which i solved 
like `min_cena(@w,@r))` ,create part never ignored that